# jQuery: Two level dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a form, and using jQuery to add dynamic fields.
The form contain a select field (*select 1* with id *childs*):

```
  $("#childs").change(function() {
    var htmlString = "";
    var num = $("option:selected", this).val(); // max value is 6.
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      htmlString += "Another set of fields";
    }
    $("#outputchilds").html(htmlString);
  });
```

This will output another set of fields on the the element with ID *outputchilds*.
Also another select field (*select 2* with id *rooms*), with the same technique for `#childs`, this is the code that generate the rooms fields:

```
  $("#rooms").change(function() {
    var htmlString = "";
    var num = $("option:selected", this).val(); // max value is 8.
    for (var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
      htmlString += 'Set of fields that contain #outputchilds element';
    }
    $("#outputrooms").html(htmlString);
  });
```

The rooms fields are generated correctly, but the childs fields (which they are contained in the rooms fields) don't show as expected.

I think the `#outputchilds` must be unique for each generated set of fields e.g: `#outputchilds-i`, but how to refactor my code then?

**Update**
application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $("#rooms").change(function() {
    var htmlString = "";
    var num = $("option:selected", this).val();
    for (var i = 1; i < num; i++) {
      htmlString += '<div class="row-fluid">'+
                      '<div class="span1">'+
                        'Room '+ (i+1) +
                      '</div>'+
                      '<div class="span2">'+
                        '<div class="control-group">'+
                          '<label class="control-label">Children:</label>'+
                          '<select class="input-mini" id="children">'+
                            '<option value="0">0</option>'+
                            '<option value="1">1</option>'+
                            '<option value="2">2</option>'+
                            '<option value="3">3</option>'+
                            '<option value="4">4</option>'+
                            '<option value="5">5</option>'+
                            '<option value="6">6</option>'+
                          '</select>'+
                        '</div>'+
                      '</div>'+
                      '<div class="span7">'+
                        '<div class="row-fluid" id="outputchilds"></div>'+
                      '</div>'+
                    '</div>';
    }
    $("#outputrooms").html(htmlString);
  });

  $("#children").change(function() {
    var htmlString = "";
    var num = $("option:selected", this).val();
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      htmlString +=   "<div class='span2'>"+
                        "<div class='control-group'>"+
                          "<label class='control-label'>Child "+ (i+1) +":</label>"+
                          "<select class='input-mini'>"+
                            "<option value='0'>0</option>"+
                            "<option value='1'>1</option>"+
                            "<option value='2' selected >2</option>"+
                            "<option value='3'>3</option>"+
                            "<option value='4'>4</option>"+
                            "<option value='5'>5</option>"+
                            "<option value='6'>6</option>"+
                            "<option value='7'>7</option>"+
                            "<option value='8'>8</option>"+
                            "<option value='9'>9</option>"+
                            "<option value='10'>10</option>"+
                            "<option value='11'>11</option>"+
                            "<option value='12'>12</option>"+
                            "<option value='13'>13</option>"+
                            "<option value='14'>14</option>"+
                            "<option value='15'>15</option>"+
                            "<option value='16'>16</option>"+
                            "<option value='17'>17</option>"+
                          "</select>"+
                        "</div>"+
                      "</div>";
    }
    $("#outputchilds").html(htmlString);
  });
})
```

index.html:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span1">
    Room 1
  </div>
  <div class="span2">
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label">Children:</label>
      <select class="input-mini" id="children">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="span7">
    <div class="row-fluid" id="outputchilds">
      <!-- Dynamic Childs Age selects -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="outputrooms">
  <!-- Rooms fields -->
</div>
```

Comment: Posted both HTML and Js files

Comment: `#children` is a dynamic added element you must handle it with `on` jQuery function

Comment: This didn't work also: `$("#children").on('change', function() {`
http://jsfiddle.net/AGuvb/

Comment: Which part is not working ,both select are adding elements, please explain where are u having trouble, sorry for bad english

Comment: @RodrigoAssis, notice that only the static select field (Room 1 > children) work.

Comment: Try adding another room, then select number of children, it will not show the appropriate fields.

Comment: Does the parent `Room 1 > children` do the same thing as their children? if it is add a class to all of them, if not add a class to the children selects and handle it events with `on`

Comment: @RodrigoAssis, can you fork this http://jsfiddle.net/AGuvb/1/ ?

Comment: This maybe not what you want but you can see what i mean http://jsfiddle.net/AGuvb/2/

Comment: See that if you choose in a second select it will delete current selects and add new ones, if you dont want that to happen change your code and tell us if anything goes wrong